# ¿Cómo hago para que mi proyecto con tailwind este listo para distribución y se apliquen los estilos?

Tags: css, hosting, tailwind, framework

Cuando lo intento subir vía hostinger con la carpeta dist se me pone la pagina sin estilos de tailwind y queda como si solo hubiese hecho en html.
No se como hacer para que mi tailwind ya este listo para distribución, de antemano mil gracias

Comment: Hola! Has comprobado que la carpeta se haya subido correctamente y que contenga todos sus archivos?

Comment: Según  yo si, mi carpeta dist contiene las imágenes que utilizo, un archivo app.js, el index.html y el output.css